# What HTTP signatures are encountered from Google web crawling robots?

Tags: http, sockets, seo

With all HTTP data available,
What 'signs' can you look for to recognize Google's search engine robots?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[How to verify googlebot](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html) - the official method.

Comment: It's probably changing unpredictably. Just use the DNS method there and you should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Google's crawlers have the user-agent set to "Googlebot".

Other search engine providers typically stick to a recognisable name in the user-agent; there are various lists of well-known agents, such as that on http://www.jafsoft.com/searchengines/webbots.html.

Answer (score 1):

The [User-Agent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User-Agent) header should be enough to detect the Google bot

Check out [user-agents.org](http://www.user-agents.org/) website to get a list of known se bot

By the you would like to want to be sure that's a true googlebot from google, then you can check out the ip/host which is always

> c[nn].googlebot.com

Where [nn] is a number.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not so sure how maintainable it is to be doing DNS reverse lookups for ip addresses. I would only do this if you were concerned about someone spoofing google's user agent strings, which is highly unlikely. It can also be spoofed itself, as the article points out.

You're best off just matching their known user agents:

```
Regex.IsMatch(ua, @"googlebot|mediapartners-google|adsbot-google", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```